# AsyncTaskLoader not refreshing the recycler view when the data is deleted using content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contentobserver, asynctaskloader

**This is how the main class looks like where the list is**

```
package com.example.android.todolist;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.android.todolist.data.TaskContract;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {


// Constants for logging and referring to a unique loader
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int TASK_LOADER_ID = 0;

// Member variables for the adapter and RecyclerView
private CustomCursorAdapter mAdapter;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set the RecyclerView to its corresponding view
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewTasks);

    // Set the layout for the RecyclerView to be a linear layout, which measures and
    // positions items within a RecyclerView into a linear list
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    // Initialize the adapter and attach it to the RecyclerView
    mAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    /*
     Add a touch helper to the RecyclerView to recognize when a user swipes to delete an item.
     An ItemTouchHelper enables touch behavior (like swipe and move) on each ViewHolder,
     and uses callbacks to signal when a user is performing these actions.
     */
    new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        // Called when a user swipes left or right on a ViewHolder
        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
            // Here is where you'll implement swipe to delete

            // COMPLETED (1) Construct the URI for the item to delete
            //[Hint] Use getTag (from the adapter code) to get the id of the swiped item
            // Retrieve the id of the task to delete
            int id = (int) viewHolder.itemView.getTag();

            // Build appropriate uri with String row id appended
            String stringId = Integer.toString(id);
            Uri uri = TaskContract.TaskEntry.CONTENT_URI;
            uri = uri.buildUpon().appendPath(stringId).build();

            // COMPLETED (2) Delete a single row of data using a ContentResolver
            getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);

            // COMPLETED (3) Restart the loader to re-query for all tasks after a deletion
            //getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(TASK_LOADER_ID, null, MainActivity.this);

        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);

    /*
     Set the Floating Action Button (FAB) to its corresponding View.
     Attach an OnClickListener to it, so that when it's clicked, a new intent will be created
     to launch the AddTaskActivity.
     */
    FloatingActionButton fabButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fabButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Create a new intent to start an AddTaskActivity
            Intent addTaskIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddTaskActivity.class);
            startActivity(addTaskIntent);
        }
    });

    /*
     Ensure a loader is initialized and active. If the loader doesn't already exist, one is
     created, otherwise the last created loader is re-used.
     */
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(TASK_LOADER_ID, null, this);
}


/**
 * This method is called after this activity has been paused or restarted.
 * Often, this is after new data has been inserted through an AddTaskActivity,
 * so this restarts the loader to re-query the underlying data for any changes.
 */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // re-queries for all tasks
    getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(TASK_LOADER_ID, null, this);
}


/**
 * Instantiates and returns a new AsyncTaskLoader with the given ID.
 * This loader will return task data as a Cursor or null if an error occurs.
 *
 * Implements the required callbacks to take care of loading data at all stages of loading.
 */
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, final Bundle loaderArgs) {

    return new AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor>(this) {

        // Initialize a Cursor, this will hold all the task data
        Cursor mTaskData = null;

        // onStartLoading() is called when a loader first starts loading data
        @Override
        protected void onStartLoading() {
            if (mTaskData != null) {
                // Delivers any previously loaded data immediately
                deliverResult(mTaskData);
            } else {
                // Force a new load
                forceLoad();
            }
        }

        // loadInBackground() performs asynchronous loading of data
        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            // Will implement to load data

            // Query and load all task data in the background; sort by priority
            // [Hint] use a try/catch block to catch any errors in loading data

            try {
                return getContentResolver().query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_PRIORITY);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to asynchronously load data.");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        // deliverResult sends the result of the load, a Cursor, to the registered listener
        public void deliverResult(Cursor data) {
            mTaskData = data;
            super.deliverResult(data);
        }
    };

}


/**
 * Called when a previously created loader has finished its load.
 *
 * @param loader The Loader that has finished.
 * @param data The data generated by the Loader.
 */
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    // Update the data that the adapter uses to create ViewHolders
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}


/**
 * Called when a previously created loader is being reset, and thus
 * making its data unavailable.
 * onLoaderReset removes any references this activity had to the loader's data.
 *
 * @param loader The Loader that is being reset.
 */
@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

}
```

**the class uses content provider sqlite database. in the swipe operation where the content is deleted it should notify directly in case of data change. i don't think that's happening**

Below is the content provider class

```
/*
* Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
*      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*/

package com.example.android.todolist.data;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import static com.example.android.todolist.data.TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME;

// Verify that TaskContentProvider extends from ContentProvider and implements required methods
public class TaskContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    // Define final integer constants for the directory of tasks and a single item.
    // It's convention to use 100, 200, 300, etc for directories,
    // and related ints (101, 102, ..) for items in that directory.
    public static final int TASKS = 100;
    public static final int TASK_WITH_ID = 101;

    // CDeclare a static variable for the Uri matcher that you construct
    private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = buildUriMatcher();

    // Define a static buildUriMatcher method that associates URI's with their int match
    /**
     Initialize a new matcher object without any matches,
     then use .addURI(String authority, String path, int match) to add matches
     */
    public static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {

        // Initialize a UriMatcher with no matches by passing in NO_MATCH to the constructor
        UriMatcher uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

        /*
          All paths added to the UriMatcher have a corresponding int.
          For each kind of uri you may want to access, add the corresponding match with addURI.
          The two calls below add matches for the task directory and a single item by ID.
         */
        uriMatcher.addURI(TaskContract.AUTHORITY, TaskContract.PATH_TASKS, TASKS);
        uriMatcher.addURI(TaskContract.AUTHORITY, TaskContract.PATH_TASKS + "/#", TASK_WITH_ID);

        return uriMatcher;
    }

    // Member variable for a TaskDbHelper that's initialized in the onCreate() method
    private TaskDbHelper mTaskDbHelper;

    /* onCreate() is where you should initialize anything you’ll need to setup
    your underlying data source.
    In this case, you’re working with a SQLite database, so you’ll need to
    initialize a DbHelper to gain access to it.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        // Complete onCreate() and initialize a TaskDbhelper on startup
        // [Hint] Declare the DbHelper as a global variable

        Context context = getContext();
        mTaskDbHelper = new TaskDbHelper(context);
        return true;
    }


    // Implement insert to handle requests to insert a single new row of data
    @Override
    public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        // Get access to the task database (to write new data to)
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mTaskDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        // Write URI matching code to identify the match for the tasks directory
        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        Uri returnUri; // URI to be returned

        switch (match) {
            case TASKS:
                // Insert new values into the database
                // Inserting values into tasks table
                long id = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
                if ( id > 0 ) {
                    returnUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(TaskContract.TaskEntry.CONTENT_URI, id);
                } else {
                    throw new android.database.SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
                }
                break;
            // Set the value for the returnedUri and write the default case for unknown URI's
            // Default case throws an UnsupportedOperationException
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
        }

        // Notify the resolver if the uri has been changed, and return the newly inserted URI
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

        // Return constructed uri (this points to the newly inserted row of data)
        return returnUri;
    }


    // Implement query to handle requests for data by URI
    @Override
    public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

        // Get access to underlying database (read-only for query)
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mTaskDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        // Write URI match code and set a variable to return a Cursor
        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        Cursor retCursor;

        // Query for the tasks directory and write a default case
        switch (match) {
            // Query for the tasks directory
            case TASKS:
                retCursor =  db.query(TABLE_NAME,
                        projection,
                        selection,
                        selectionArgs,
                        null,
                        null,
                        sortOrder);
                break;
            // Default exception
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
        }

        // Set a notification URI on the Cursor and return that Cursor
        retCursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

        // Return the desired Cursor
        return retCursor;
    }


    // Implement delete to delete a single row of data
    @Override
    public int delete(@NonNull Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

        // Get access to the database and write URI matching code to recognize a single item
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mTaskDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        // Keep track of the number of deleted tasks
        int tasksDeleted; // starts as 0

        // Write the code to delete a single row of data
        // [Hint] Use selections to delete an item by its row ID
        switch (match) {
            // Handle the single item case, recognized by the ID included in the URI path
            case TASK_WITH_ID:
                // Get the task ID from the URI path
                String id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
                // Use selections/selectionArgs to filter for this ID
                tasksDeleted = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id=?", new String[]{id});
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
        }

        // Notify the resolver of a change and return the number of items deleted
        if (tasksDeleted != 0) {
            // A task was deleted, set notification
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        }

        // Return the number of tasks deleted
        return tasksDeleted;
    }


    @Override
    public int update(@NonNull Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
                      String[] selectionArgs) {

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }


    @Override
    public String getType(@NonNull Uri uri) {

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.

1. CustomCursorAdapter - If you extends from CursorAdapter, check your constructor's super method which has a 3rd param called flgs. That handles the auto query part of the cursor.
2. Since you're already using the LoaderCallbacks, You can directly use the cursor loader instead of AsyncTaskLoader

   ```
   @Override
   public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, final Bundle loaderArgs) {
      return new CursorLoader(context, uri, projection, selection, mSelectionArgs, sortOrder);
   }
   ```